# mutator methods with Fixnum and Symbol

Tags: ruby

In matz's book, Ruby Programming Language, he says the following:

> We've said that all values in Ruby are objects and all objects are
>   manipulated by reference. In the reference implementation, however,
>   Fixnum and Symbol objects are actually "immediate values" rather than
>   references. Neither of these classes have mutator methods, so Fixnum
>   and Symbol objects are immutable...The only practical difference
>   between immediate values and reference values is that immediate values
>   cannot have singleton methods defined on them.

So I launch irb and test this claim.

```
class Symbol
  def self.mutator
    puts 'mutator method'
  end
end

Symbol.mutator
# => mutator method
```

I just defined a singleton method on Symbol, without errors. So what is he talking about?

Comment: @Mohamad I understand that, but did you read the quote above? The quote is not talking about assignment. It is talking about singleton methods.

Comment: He said singleton methods cannot be defined on immediate objects, `Symbol` is not an immediate object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [...] immediate values cannot have singleton methods defined on them

Singleton method is one you define on an object of instance of class, not on class (object) itself, like in the example you've provided.

Consider following code:

```
s = :sym

def s.my_method
  puts "HELLO"
end
# => TypeError: can't define singleton
```

When on other object, eg of `string`:

```
str = "string"

def str.my_method
  puts "HELLO"
end

str.my_method
# => HELLO
```

The second one is without any errors.

Hope that helps!

**UPDATE - what are immediate values**

> Fixnum are objects that contain immediate values
>
> What does it means? It means that if we write x = 5, the number 5 will
>   be stored (encoded) directly into the variable x like if it was a
>   primitive data type (with ruby traditional objects, x would have
>   contained an address corresponding to the object stored in the heap).
>   So, when we write x = 5, x knows everything it needs about the number
>   5. In fact, x IS the object and not a reference to it.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732160/mutator-methods-with-fixnum-and-symbol/29732229#29732214)

Let's consider an example:

```
fix1 = 2
fix2 = 2

fix1.object_id
# => 5

fix2.object_id
# => 5
```

But:

```
str1 = "test"
str2 = "test"

str1.object_id
# => 2157416420

str2.object_id
# => 2157531060
```

`Fixnum`s of the same value have exactly the same `object_id` (the same applies to `Symbol`), but to `String`s, even if they are of the similar value `"test"`, they have different `object_id`s.

Because immediate values are immutable (are allocating the same place in memory), they can't be mutable.

Comment: It was the definition of "immediate values" which was unclear to me.